# Android (Xamarin) get height of view

Tags: android, xamarin, layout

How do I get the height of a gridview that I'm implementing? Simply calling gridview.Height returns a 0, since the grid hasn't been drawn at the time I called it, thus after looking around I learnt that I have to implement a view tree observer. I did manage to get the height successfully, but I'm unable to use it due being unable to stop the view tree observer and retrieve the height. I've also found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42575932/how-to-remove-viewtreeobserver-in-xamarin), but it is unresolved.

Here is my code:

```
//  Get gridview height
ViewTreeObserver vto = gridview.ViewTreeObserver;
vto.GlobalLayout += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (GRID_HEIGHT > 0)
    {
        GRID_HEIGHT = gridview.Height;

        //  Configure gridview            
        gridview.Adapter = new CustomAdapter(this);

        return;
    }
};
```

When the code is executed, it just loops on forever. How can I exit the loop, or is there another way to get the height of the gridview? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `Post` method in any view like:

```
int height = 0;
gridview.Post(() =>
{
    height = grid.Height;        
});
```

Comment: Glad that helped.